# javascript disabled - youtube videos playing

Tags: javascript, youtube

Can anybody explain to me how are YouTube videos playing even with disabled JavaScript in browser? Is there any server side scripting or any other technique involved? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have an example? Might be just HTML5 video player?

Comment: Video Player of Youtube is a Flash Player not developed in Javascript. It will play without javacript

Comment: @putvande you wouldn't be able to control HTML5 video without JS (in the way that YouTube does)

Comment: @m90: But you can still play it :-)  It *might* fallback to the browser's built-in HTML5 video controls.

Comment: @KailashAhirwar that is not really true, Flash implementation on YT requires JS

Comment: @m90 simply add `<video src="" />` element and it will play without JS :)

Comment: @FlashThunder that's what I meant saying "(in the way that YouTube does) "

Comment: FWIW I don't see any video when disabling JS in FF by the way and there is no `<video>` element present in the source code

Comment: Because FF does not support `mp4` :-)

Comment: @FlashThunder but how does the mp4 get there without a video tag then? Browser Sniffing?

Comment: @m90 No, Youtube simply serves raw mp4 file, in video thumbnail anchor, when there is no other option. Exactly the same way as on Windows Mobile phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube serves pure mp4 files, if your browser supports HTML5 or you got any other player plugin installed, it will work this way. On cellphones without HTML5 support or Flash, you may simply download those files. Flash player implementation on Youtube does not work without js.

Answer (score 0):

I see YouTube player use an Adobe Flash not HTML5 :)
Player in HTML5 (not by default) doesn't work without JS. (most YouTube buttons, options and others too)

Comment: You see? Did you at least check it out? Of course most functions don't work, but at least it plays / serves video. Flash Player can not even be initialized without js.